# What algorithm in 'zsh' shell when it run "cat < 11 < 22 < 33 > 55 > 66"?

Tags: c, unix, zsh

I write own shell, and I can't understand logic, what standard shell do with file descriptors before function `execve()` in this case `cat < 11 < 22 < 33 > 55 > 66`. How I see it, we open files 11, 22, 33, open or create files 55, 66, then we must create some `pipe()` or something like this, and run three times `dup2(fd(11), 0)`, `dup2(pip[1], 1)`, `execve()`, where each time we change `fd()` on 11, 22, 33. And after that two times `dup2(pip[0], 0)`, `dup2(fd(55), 1)`, `execve()`, and the same with fd(66)?
But in case `wc < 11 < 22 < 33 > 55 > 66` it's must not will work, it write three `wc` command in 55 and 66, but standard shall take sum of tree files and result of `wc` command write into the files 55 and 66.
How does it work?

Comment: What is "the standard shell"? For bash, it doesn't seem to support multiple `<`s in the same command. And bash is not generally minimalist, which leads me to suspect that other shells don't, either ...

Comment: Sorry, I mean in `zsh`.

Comment: This is a non-standard feature in zsh called "MULTIOS". You can read about it in zshmisc(1). It can be turned off with `setopt nomultios`. The reason it's only in zsh and not in other shells is that implementing it is harder. The standard redirection operators are basically the ones that are trivial to implement with `open`, `close`, and `dup2`

Comment: Thanks man, i will read about it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  Wumpus Q. Wumbley, I understand what happens in zsh when it run this command `wc < 11 < 22 < 33 > 55 > 66`. 
Maybe somebody wants to know it, I write what I understand.
After open all file descriptors of files (11, 22, 33, 55, 66), we make a `pipe(pip[])`. Then one by one we run in each child process `dup2(fd(11), 0)` and `dup2(pip[1], 1)`, end `execve("/bin/cat", "cat", env)`, then repeat it with `fd(22)` and `fd(33)`.
And after that we run in next child processes `dup2(pip[0], 0)`, `dup2(fd(55), 1)` end here we make `ecxecve(".../wc", "wc", env)`, end repeat for fd(66).